# How to make vite ignore `<docs>` blocks?

Tags: vuejs3, vite, vue-sfc

I want to use `<docs>` blocks in my `*.vue` files to add documentation to components.
These blocks are correctly interpreted by `vue-docgen-cli`, but file compilation fails because `vite` is reading inside the block. For example, compilation of this SFC file fails with error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'is'`:

```
<docs>
This is my component.
</docs>
<script setup lang="ts">
. . .
</script>
```

Is there a way to make `vite` ignore `<docs>` blocks? There is `vite-plugin-vuedoc` that seems useful, but the package does not install.

Thanks for your help!
mario

#### Environment

- vue 3.2.45
- vite 4.0.0
- Windows 11
- node 18.12.1

Answer (score 2):

Found a way. In `vite.config.ts` add the following code (from https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/9301#discussioncomment-3224059):

```
const vueDocsPlugin = {
  name: 'vue-docs',
  transform(_code: unknown, id: string) {
    if(!/vue&type=docs/.test(id)) return
    return `export default ''`
  }
}
```

Then in the `plugins` array add `vueDocsPlugin`.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. this works!

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use a plugin for that.

Vite plugins are compatible with rollup plugin structure, so you may be able to use the [rollup-plugin-re](https://github.com/jetiny/rollup-plugin-re) plugin to remove the desired content using a regexp. You could also write your own plugin that does exactly what you need.